# How do I use Google Wallet through PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, payment, android-pay, jwt

I am currently really the most stuck I've ever been, implementing [Google Wallet](http://google.com/wallet) with PHP. I've been studying it for the past two weeks with little to no luck.

I'm not the only one stuck in this regard.  Where do I begin?  My internet searches for tutorials and documentation have been fruitless.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka but that is for checkout not wallet please see: http://www.google.com/wallet/ wallet is for In-App Perchases

Comment: ah, sorry. What kind of API does Wallet expose? Questions just asking for a tutorial aren't really on-topic on SO. You may be luckier finding a generic tutorial on how to deal with web services.

Comment: Have you got some code so far, Ben? If so, edit your question and add it in. Specifically if you're getting an error message, or unexpected API behaviour, that's where SO can step in and help.

Comment: Are you talking about implementing the [Google Payment Express API](https://developers.google.com/payment-express/)?  That's the only thing outside of Checkout that I was able to track down that accepts payment via Google Wallet.  Google Wallet *itself* seems to have no web service API, as it's an exclusively mobile-device mechanism.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like Google's implementation of in-app payments [also uses Wallet](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/purchaseflow), though it looks like the only server-side thing involved is [accepting an informative postback](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/postback) after [doing the rest in Javascript](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial).

Comment: no theres also a bit with jwt signatures that they left out of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial for Google Wallet in their documentation involving PHP. Their sample code works and is easily modified to use in a test/production environment. Keep in mind that you do have to change several elements when going from sandbox to production. Do not assume you keys and ID's will be the same in both environments as they will not.

Settings page: checkout.google.com/inapp/merchant/settings.html

Sample code and documentation (limited explanation, but if you know PHP, no problem):

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/

code.google.com/p/iap-php/source/browse